# Time zone abbreviations ET, CT, MT, PT

Tags: php, datetime, time

Is this correct?

Is there some built-in PHP way of doing this or a library I should be using instead of this custom function?

```
/**
 * Supports the 4 Generalized Time Zones shown here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa of the contiguous U.S. (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Time_in_the_United_States&oldid=885295732#Zones_used_in_the_contiguous_U.S.)
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database
 * 
 * @param string $ianatz
 * @return string
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public static function getUsaGeneralizedTimeZoneAbbrev($ianatz) {
    if ($ianatz == 'America/New_York') {
        return 'ET';
    } else if ($ianatz == 'America/Chicago') {
        return 'CT';
    } else if ($ianatz == 'America/Phoenix') {
        return 'MT';
    } else if ($ianatz == 'America/Los_Angeles') {
        return 'PT';
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Please use one of the 4 supported time zones of the contiguous USA.');
    }
}
```

Note: I am NOT interested in EDT vs EST. I want the *generalized* version (ET) so that the change in season doesn't make the label incorrect (e.g. for a form input that could accept a date of any season).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the value provided in `$ianatz`?

Comment: @GlenSolsberry I want short abbreviations such as "ET" instead of the clunky long "America/New_York" form.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Timezone Abbreviation.

```php
$dateTime = new DateTime(); 
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 

$dateTime->format('T'); // CST
```

But I would suggest using UTC in forms which do not have DST.

[Wikipedia UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but local time or civil time may change if a time zone jurisdiction observes daylight saving time or summer time. For example, UTC is 5 hours ahead of local time on the east coast of the United States during winter, but 4 hours ahead during summer.

Also, I would suggest reading a great article by Zach Holman [UTC is enough for everyone right?](https://zachholman.com/talk/utc-is-enough-for-everyone-right)

Comment: You could also suggest just stripping the middle character from `$dateTime->format('T')` to give OP the result he desires.

Comment: @Oleg I specifically said in my question that the 3-letter abbreviations such as CST are not what I want. However, I really appreciated the link to the funny and informative article. :-)